# Как использовать Laravel auth для двух разных пользователях

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel

Мое приложение имеет возможность авторизации двух разных пользователей,
***Докторов*** и ***Пациентов***, с различными полями ввода.
Как  использовать возможности *Laravel auth* для этих двух различных сушностей
Если возможно дайте *ссылку*  или  *объясните подробно*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M&list=PLwAKR305CRO9S6KVHMJYqZpjPzGPWuQ7Q

Comment: Очевидно, что вам нужны роли

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в таблицу users поле role ('1' или '2' соответственно для пац. или докт.) и при авторизации отправлять в контроллер через $request значение для этого поля в зависимости от того,какой тип авторизуется.